# How to specified pharPath on VSCode settings.json file in Ubuntu 20.04, for using PHP Formatter extension?

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

I have installed PHP Formatter extension on VSCode. I' trying to Format Document but I have this log:

```
Neither a pharPath or use of Composer was specified. Aborting...
```

I installed php based on [Ondrej PHP PPA](https://tecadmin.net/how-to-install-php-8-on-ubuntu-20-04/).

How can I specified the pharPath?

Comment: If you're using vysker's vscode-php-formatter plugin, this is [a five year old known issue](https://github.com/vysker/vscode-php-formatter/issues/17). If you're not using that plugin, then you may want to get in touch with whoever wrote it, as there's very little on the Internet for that particular issue.

Comment: @matigo, can you recommend me a php formatter plugin that works? (I'm new with php)

Comment: I do not use VScode, but some of my colleagues suggest using `phpfmt` instead.